# Trying to rewrite /directory/dir_variable/ to /directory/dir_variable/index.php

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite something like this:

domain.tld/staging/base_1/ to domain.tld/staging/base_1/index.php where '1' is a variable number.

but am getting a redirect cycle.

```
*1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/staging/base_1//index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php ....
```

Here's the location directive I'm using which I've read the docs and this seems like it would work, but I'm obviously missing something.

```
location ~* /staging/(.*) {
    rewrite ^/staging/(.*)$ /staging/$1/index.php last;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to re-read the doc as it's explained here :

> ```
> Syntax:   rewrite regex replacement [flag];
> Default:  —
> Context:  server, location, if
> ```
>
> [ ... ]
>
> ```
> An optional flag parameter can be one of:
>
> last 
>    stops processing the current set of ngx_http_rewrite_module
>    directives and starts a search for a new location matching the changed
>    URI;
>
> break
>     stops processing the current set of ngx_http_rewrite_module
>     directives as with the break directive;
>
> redirect returns a temporary
>     redirect with the 302 code; used if a replacement string does not
>     start with “http://” or “https://”; permanent returns a permanent
>     redirect with the 301 code.
> ```

So when you use the `last` flag it's like an internal redirect to nginx. I'm guessing you declared a `location ~ \.php$` block **after** this one, in order to process php files but it won't be picked in the location election process because the first matching regex wins. Thus it enters the former location block recursively.

Comment: I see, this makes much more sense.  I was thinking I needed to include the php location block as a separate entity but this makes much more sense.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
location ~* /staging/(.*) {
    rewrite ^/staging/(.*)/$ /staging/$1/index.php break;
}
```

or to limit to one level:

```
location ~* /staging/(*) {
    rewrite ^/staging/([^/]*)/$ /staging/$1/index.php break;
}
```

Comment: That does work, sort of.  I'm now stuck with it downloading the index.php as a file.  Do you think that could be a problem with the php location block?